# python how to sort a list on 2 values

Tags: python, sorting

If I have a the list

```
listOfFiles = [<str>,<intA>,<intB>]
```

How can I sort this list first by intA then by intB?

The end result would look like

```
<str>,1,1
<str>,1,2
<str>,1,3
<str>,2,1
<str>,2,2
etc
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a compound key (or rather, a sequence as a key).

```
listOfFiles.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1, 2))
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know that you could pass multiple arguments to `operator.itemgetter`.

Answer (score 0):

Python list sorting is done in place and is guaranteed to be stable after 2.4 (I believe, it may have been 2.5).  That means you can sort like so and should get the results you want:

```
listOfFiles.sort(key = lambda x: x[2])

listOfFiles.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])
```

I presume you actually have a list of lists, or a list of tuples.  If not, please provide a more complete example of your data structure.

Comment: I would just make the lambda x[1], x[2] so you only need to sort once.

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
listOfFiles.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1], x[2]))
```